# Protractor cssContainingText with function as argument

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm trying to test if my input field calculates credits correctly.

This test should pick a random number between 1-100(credits) and then multiply them by 5($) and display a total price.

```js
function randomZip() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
}
var creditQuantity = randomZip();

function creditQuantityMultiplied() {
  creditQuantity * 5;
  return;
};

element(by.css("a[href='/credits']")).click();
element(by.css('input[name="count"]')).sendKeys(creditQuantity);
$('.text_per').click();
browser.sleep(1500);

var checkSumCredits = element(by.cssContainingText('.inline-block.price_credit.text_per', creditQuantityMultiplied()));

expect(checkSumCredits.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
```

```html
<div class="credits-block" id="creditsBuyForm">
  <h2>Buy Credits</h2>
  <div class="credits">
    <div class="block">
      <span class="text_per">Amount</span>
      <input type="text" name="count" value="25" class="text_per">
      <span class="text_per">x</span>
      <div class="inline-block price_credit">$5.00</div>
      <span class="text_per">per credit</span> </div>
    <div class="block">
      <span class="text_per">Total</span>
      <div class="inline-block price_credit text_per">
        <img width="32" height="32" src="/app-static/css/img/coins_2.png" class="inline-block"> $125.00</div>
      <div class="inline-block">
        <form action="/cart/index.php" method="post" id="remoteadd" class="trackable-init">
          <input type="hidden" name="app" value="ecom"> <input type="hidden" name="ns" value="addcart">
          <input type="hidden" name="cart_api" value="Y"> <input type="hidden" name="price" value="5.00">
          <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Credits ($5.00 per credit)">
          <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="25">
          <input type="hidden" name="number" value="a:3:{s:7:&quot;user_id&quot;;i:7996;s:10:&quot;company_id&quot;;i:1;s:9:&quot;item_type&quot;;i:1;}">
          <input type="hidden" name="delivery_method" value="N">
          <input type="hidden" name="SUBMIT" value="SUBMIT">
          <input type="hidden" name="taxcountry" value="STANDARD">
          <input type="hidden" name="taxstateprov" value="STANDARD"> <input type="hidden" name="taxclass" value="DIGITAL">
          <button type="submit" class="def-ui-button-buy ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-primary" role="button">
            <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-cart"></span>
            <span class="ui-button-text">Buy</span>
            </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm getting Expected false to be truthy when I run this code and I'm not sure if the problem is that cssContainingText requires 2 string args and im passing 1 string 1 integer or something else.

Comment: Both parameters must be of type `string`.  http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText

Comment: var creditQuantity = randomZip();
  var creditQuantityMultiplied = creditQuantity * 5;
  function creditQuantityToStr(){
   creditQuantityMultiplied.toString();
     };


  element(by.css("a[href='/credits']")).click().then(function () {
   element(by.css('input[name="count"]')).sendKeys(creditQuantity);
   $('.text_per').click().then(function () {
    browser.sleep(1500);
    var checkSumCredits = element(by.cssContainingText('.inline-block.price_credit.text_per', creditQuantityToStr()));
    expect(checkSumCredits.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
   });
Still getting Falsy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I look at your code I see the following happening

1. You fill `element(by.css('input[name="count"]'))` with `creditQuantity`, which is random generated, for example it is value `47`
2. You are then doing an assertion with `expect(checkSumCredits.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();`. `checkSumCredits` is based on the fact if it can find an element that holds the value that is generated with `creditQuantityMultiplied()`

The `creditQuantityMultiplied()` holds 2 errors in my opinion:

1. It doesn't return a value, it only `return`'s
2. If you change `creditQuantityMultiplied()` to also return a value it will also generate a unique value. That will never equal the previous random value of 47

That's why you won't find a match and will return `false` / fail.

Hope it helps